# Why only two isomorphism classes of semi direct products?

Tags: group-theory

http://www-groups.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~colva/topics/solns5.pdf

I'm studying semi direct products and I linked a homework set with solutions above.  I'm interested in problem 10-b.  I'm not convinced that there are only 2 groups up to isomorphism of a group of order $pq$ when $p\mid q-1$.  How do we know that there isn't another homomorphism (besides trivial/conjugation ) that gives us yet another product?

Comment: There are certainly more than one homomorphism, but that does not really seem to be your issue since you call them trivial and conjugation. Once we pick a homomorphism, this will "become" conjugation in the semidirect product. The important thing here is that the $p-1$ different choices of a non-trivial homomorphism lead to isomorphic semidirect products, which is quite straightforward to check.

Comment: Why are there only p-1 choices of a non-trivial homomorphism?

Comment: Because there is a unique subgroup of order $p$, so by picking a generator of the domain, the non-trivial homomorphism is uniquely determined by its image (which must be a generator).